# How to save an image from webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

Ya guys i have tried a lot of answers on this website and that all doesn't work at all
 I have a webview app that i would love to save image in the website.
 I have implemented long press to copy text in the app.
but not able to save image on long press.
those answers on context is not working

this is my main activity code can anyone please edit and answer me
and keep in mind that i only have some basic coding in java and I made most of this  app from the codes of different sources

My Main Activity:

```
package com.example.ragulsundaram.typicaltamilan;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView mWebView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    private long backPressedTime;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static int TIME_OUT=4000;




    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()){
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Press back again to exit,",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            switch (keyCode){

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mWebView.canGoBack()){

                        mWebView.goBack();
                    }
                    else {

                        if(backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()){
                            super.onBackPressed();

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Press back again to exit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pogatheeey",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Vankakkam",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
        {
            public void onRefresh(){
                LoadWeb();
            }
        });

        LoadWeb();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(permissions,1);
            }
        }
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mWebView.reload();

            }
        });

    }





    public void LoadWeb()
    {
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://typicaltamila.blogspot.com/   ");
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        mWebView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
                new ValueCallback<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String value)
                    {
                        Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
                    }
                });
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



            public void onReveivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
                mWebView.loadUrl("file://android_asset/error.html");
            }





            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                //hide the swipe refreshlayout
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {

                if (url.startsWith("magnet")) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    try {
                        startActivity(i);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Team localpeers:  No bittorent client installed in system.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
            //torrent
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url=request.getUrl().toString();
                if (url.startsWith("magnet")) { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    try {
                        startActivity(i);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Team localpeers:  No bittorent client installed in Android.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }




        });

//downloading files

        mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request= new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setMimeType(mimetype);
                String cookies = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie",cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
                request.setDescription(("Downloading"));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype));
                DownloadManager dm=(DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your file is downloading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




            }
        });

    }

}
```